# How to permanently set i915.modeset=0 to fix black screen after boot on device with Intel graphics card

Tags: wubi, intel-graphics

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 in dual mode with Windows 7. The screen goes black after the initial boot.

I have tried editing GRUB in the initial boot by typing `i915.modeset=0` and it works, but how can I do it permanently? I am using HP G62 laptop with intel HD graphics.

Answer (score 4):

In a terminal window, type

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

locate the following line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

add `i915.modeset=0` in between the quotes, the end result looking like this

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i915.modeset=0"
```

lastly, run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: I have tried but its not working; may be I am not following it correctly. as per my knowledge Alt+F2 brings window for running a command. On writing gksudo gedit /etc/dfault/grub it shows blank grub however on gksu gedit /etc/dfault/grub it opens grub. I edit it, save it and run sudo update-grub in run command window. then close editor. however once I boot again there is no change and screen goes black. once I edit grub during boot it does not show any change in grub file. I am unable to understand. plz help me out

Comment: The first command had a typo, which is fixed now. You can verify that the `i915.modeset=0` has been added by running `cat /proc/cmdline` in a terminal window (not alt-f2). The output should include the said option.

Comment: plz elaborate how to go to terminal window in  in 12.04

Comment: It Ubuntu 12.04, you can either search for 'terminal' in the Dash, or use ctrl-alt-t key combination.

Comment: Apparently the problem has been solved. I have just installed the system updates and change in grub is now permanent.         Thanks a lot. Now plz help me with other problems:-              firstly, there are two Ubuntu in start up screen beside win 7.   secondly, I can't adjust screen resolution. it is fixed at 1024 x 768.

Comment: Glad the original problem is solved. If you think that my answer above helped, please accept it. As for any other problems, post them as separate questions with decent descriptions, and I'll do my best to help. To decribe a problem well, simple tell what exactly is wrong. For example, if you can't change the screen resolution, explain why not, cause I've no idea why you can't change it.